# Create a toolbar in c# that analyzes webpage text

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, toolbar

I wanted to know if this was at all possible before I started researching. We have phones that come equipped with a javascript dialing api. Basically we open a webpage that is

```
phone.htm?ip=xxx&dialNumber=xxx
```

Is it possible to create an internet explorer toolbar to scan all the text on a webpage and either: show the phone numbers on the webpage in the toolbar, so they can click and delete them OR replace all the phone numbers on the webpage with links? Which would be more practical?

Comment: Yes, both should be possible

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, what you are trying to do is similar to the Skype's Click-To-Call

http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/click-to-call/

I advice you to follow the same thing that they did where the numbers in webpages turns into links